# algorithmic: Reduce space between floatname and caption when unnumbered

Tags: spacing, floats, numbering, algorithms

I want to use the `algorithmic` package unnumbered.

I tried to do this with `\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}`, but it seems that the space between the floatname Algorithm and the caption great is to big.

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{great}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE dummy
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{great}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE dummy
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using unnumbered algorithms requires you to remove the numbering in two locations. The first is in the algorithms' `\caption`, while the second is in the ToC. The patch below removes exactly that:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% Remove \thealgorithm from ToC
\patchcmd{\@float@c@algorithm}% <cmd>
  {\@nameuse{the#1}}% <search>
  {}% <replace>
  {}{}% <succes><failure>
% Remove \thealgorithm from \caption
\renewcommand{\fnum@algorithm}{\fname@algorithm}
\makeatother
```

The following example shows the difference:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\listofalgorithms

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{great}
\end{algorithm}

\makeatletter
% Remove \thealgorithm from ToC
\patchcmd{\@float@c@algorithm}% <cmd>
  {\@nameuse{the#1}}% <search>
  {}% <replace>
  {}{}% <succes><failure>
% Remove \thealgorithm from \caption
\renewcommand{\fnum@algorithm}{\fname@algorithm}
\makeatother

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{great}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Note that the algorithm counter is still stepped, but that might not be a problem if *all* your algorithms should be unnumbered. If you want only some to be unnumbered, it would be best to create a separate environment to differentiate between the types.

---

If you want the spacing in the ToC to also be adjusted so you don't have a big gap between the margin and the algorithm caption, then you can remove the entire `\numberline` insertion into the `.loa` using this patch instead:

```
\makeatletter
% Remove \thealgorithm from ToC
\patchcmd{\@float@c@algorithm}% <cmd>
  {\protect\numberline{\@nameuse{the#1}}}% <search>
  {}% <replace>
  {}{}% <succes><failure>
% Remove \thealgorithm from \caption
\renewcommand{\fnum@algorithm}{\fname@algorithm}
\makeatother
```

[image]

---

Loading [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) interferes with the above update. Specifically, the `\caption` isn't set in the usual way. So, we can capture the usual `algorithm`'s `\caption` before loading `subcaption` and replace it back with the first call to `\begin{algorithm}`:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\makeatletter
\let\alg@caption\caption% Store \caption in \alg@caption
\makeatother
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% Remove \thealgorithm from ToC
\patchcmd{\@float@c@algorithm}% <cmd>
  {\@nameuse{the#1}}% <search>
  {}% <replace>
  {}{}% <succes><failure>
% Remove \thealgorithm from \caption
\renewcommand{\fnum@algorithm}{\fname@algorithm}
% Redeploy \caption at \begin{algorithm}
\g@addto@macro\fst@algorithm{\let\caption\alg@caption}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I use the `subcaption` package, which causes a bug...

Comment: @Ben: I'll work on an update later...

Comment: Do you have a solution? just don't want to be forgotten

Comment: @Ben: See then post-ending update.

Answer (score 1):

If the `subcaption` (or `caption`) package is used anyway the `caption` package option `labelformat=unnumbered` could be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelformat=unnumbered}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{great}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE dummy
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```